# The function of this pointer in derived class constructor

Tags: c++

The codes below are taken from the book *Starting Out with C++* by Tony Gaddis. What makes me confused the most is the derived class copy constructor, especially the use of this pointer. In this case, which object is being pointed by the this pointer? In my opinion, it is an object belongs to class `SearchableVector` (the one on the left side of "=", not the reference one inside the parentheses). For example if we write this line in `main()` function:

```
SearchableVector<int> intTable2 = intTable
```

Then the this pointer will point to `intTable2`? Also, if this is correct, then what is the value of `this->size()`? Since `intTable2` has just been created an it contains nothing, is the size 0?

This is the code for the `SimpleVector` class:

```
// SimpleVector class template
#ifndef SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#define SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <new>       // Needed for bad_alloc exception
#include <cstdlib>   // Needed for the exit function
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SimpleVector
{
private:
   T *aptr;          // To point to the allocated array
   int arraySize;    // Number of elements in the array
   void memError();  // Handles memory allocation errors
   void subError();  // Handles subscripts out of range

public:
   // Default constructor
   SimpleVector()
      { aptr = 0; arraySize = 0;}

   // Constructor declaration
   SimpleVector(int);

   // Copy constructor declaration
   SimpleVector(const SimpleVector &);

   // Destructor declaration
   ~SimpleVector();

   // Accessor to return the array size
   int size() const
      { return arraySize; }

   // Accessor to return a specific element
   T getElementAt(int position);

   // Overloaded [] operator declaration
   T &operator[](const int &);
};

//***********************************************************
// Constructor for SimpleVector class. Sets the size of the *
// array and allocates memory for it.                       *
//***********************************************************

template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(int s)
{
   arraySize = s;
   // Allocate memory for the array.
   try
   {
      aptr = new T [s];
   }
   catch (bad_alloc)
   {
      memError();
   }

   // Initialize the array.
   for (int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
      *(aptr + count) = 0;
}

//*******************************************
// Copy Constructor for SimpleVector class. *
//*******************************************

template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(const SimpleVector &obj)
{
   // Copy the array size.
   arraySize = obj.arraySize;

   // Allocate memory for the array.
   aptr = new T [arraySize];
   if (aptr == 0)
      memError();

   // Copy the elements of obj's array.
   for(int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
      *(aptr + count) = *(obj.aptr + count);
}

//**************************************
// Destructor for SimpleVector class.  *
//**************************************

template <class T>
SimpleVector<T>::~SimpleVector()
{
   if (arraySize > 0)
      delete [] aptr;
}

//*******************************************************
// memError function. Displays an error message and     *
// terminates the program when memory allocation fails. *
//*******************************************************

template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::memError()
{
   cout << "ERROR:Cannot allocate memory.\n";
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//***********************************************************
// subError function. Displays an error message and         *
// terminates the program when a subscript is out of range. *
//***********************************************************

template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::subError()
{
   cout << "ERROR: Subscript out of range.\n";
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//*******************************************************
// getElementAt function. The argument is a subscript.  *
// This function returns the value stored at the sub-   *
// cript in the array.                                  *
//*******************************************************

template <class T>
T SimpleVector<T>::getElementAt(int sub)
{
   if (sub < 0 || sub >= arraySize)
      subError();
   return aptr[sub];
}

//*******************************************************
// Overloaded [] operator. The argument is a subscript. *
// This function returns a reference to the element     *
// in the array indexed by the subscript.               *
//*******************************************************

template <class T>
T &SimpleVector<T>::operator[](const int &sub)
{
   if (sub < 0 || sub >= arraySize)
      subError();
   return aptr[sub];
}
#endif
```

This is the code for the derived class SearchableVector:

```
#ifndef SEARCHABLEVECTOR_H
#define SEARCHABLEVECTOR_H
#include "SimpleVector.h"

template <class T>
class SearchableVector : public SimpleVector<T>
{
public:
   // Default constructor
   SearchableVector() : SimpleVector<T>()
      {}

   // Constructor
   SearchableVector(int size) : SimpleVector<T>(size)
      { }

   // Copy constructor
   SearchableVector(SearchableVector &);

   // Accessor to find an item
   int findItem(const T);
};

//*******************************************************
// Copy constructor                                     *
//*******************************************************

template <class T>
SearchableVector<T>::SearchableVector(SearchableVector &obj):
                     SimpleVector<T>(obj.size())
{
   std::cout << this->size() << std::endl;
   for(int count = 0; count < this->size(); count++)
      this->operator[](count) = obj[count];
}

//*******************************************************
// findItem function                                    *
// This function searches for item. If item is found    *
// the subscript is returned. Otherwise -1 is returned. *
//*******************************************************

template <class T>
int SearchableVector<T>::findItem(const T item)
{
   for (int count = 0; count <= this->size(); count++)
   {
      if (this->getElementAt(count) == item)
         return count;
   }
   return -1;
}
#endif
```

I've been badly stuck for hours since yesterday but I'm still trying to figure it out. I hope you guys can help me out with these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a constructor, `this` always points to the object being constructed.  (For other member functions, it points to the object the member function was called on.)

All of the uses of `this->` can be removed, as they are not needed here.  If there is a parameter or local variable in a member function that has the same name as a member of the class, then using `this->` can be necessary to refer to the class member (although renaming the variable to avoid confusion is often preferable).

Removing `this->` will leave `operator[](count)`, which is legal but could be rewritten as `(*this)[count]` (where using `this` is necessary).

Since `template <class T> SearchableVector<T>::SearchableVector(SearchableVector &obj)` defines a copy constructor, the base class `SimpleVector<T>` will be copied first.  Then when `size()` is called, it will return the copied size (which will be the size of the vector being copied).  Note that the parameter for a copy constructor is usually a `const &`, since you shouldn't be modifying the value passed in.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Then, in this situation, `this` is pointing to an object of class SearchableVector? But actually when I move the cursor on `this`, it says that it is pointing to SimpleVector, which I dont really understand.

Comment: @Victor10214 What function are you in when you "move the cursor on `this`"?  Is this in your debugger or your IDE?  In the `SimpleVector` constructor `this` points at a `SimpleVector` (because while the memory space has been allocated for the derived class, it hasn't been constructed yet), and within the `SearchableVector` constructor that same pointer now points to a `SearchableVector` object.

Comment: Okay so basically in `SearchableVector<T>::SearchableVector(SearchableVector &obj): SimpleVector<T>(obj.size())`, `this` is firstly pointing to a SimpleVector object. Then, since now the derived class constructor is running, the same `this` is now pointing to a SearchableVector. I wonder if I got it correctly?